# prevent rpmbuild from reading ~/.rpmmacros

Tags: linux, rpm, rhel, rpmbuild, building

Is there a way to prevent the `rpmbuild` command from reading the `~/.rpmmacros` file? I want to add `rpmbuild` to a Make target and want to get a consistent build under any user account, regardless of the options somebody might have personally set in the `rpmmacros` file in his home directory.

How can I do this? Or, is that actually a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this now this by setting `$HOME` to an empty directory while running rpmbuild:

```
mkdir $MY_DIST_DIR/dummyhome
HOME=$MY_DIST_DIR/dummyhome/ rpmbuild ...
rm -r $MY_DIST_DIR/dummyhome
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to get the a consistent build then the rpmmacros is only one part of the problem.  The build may still differ simply because it's running on a machine with different things installed.  Use mock to get a truly consistent build environment.

Comment: Good point! So far I'm not aiming for a really consistent build (just want to allow building under any account regardless of personal settings), but in the long run Mock might be a better solution.